# discord.py How do I play specific mp3s (or specific youtube videos) in discord voice channels?

Tags: discord, discord.py

Now bare in mind, I'm quite the beginner so I'm not sure how to solve this problem, and many tutorials are pre-rewrite. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Please put a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example in the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

In order to play an mp3 file, you must make sure you download ***FFMPEG*** from the link [here](https://ffmpeg.org/). Once that is installed & extracted add it to your path

**Instructions for adding to path**
Control panel --> system --> advanced --> environmental variables --> system variables --> path --> then add the bin file in the files you just downloaded.

Once you have that installed, in your code you must make a VoiceClient object. There are multiple ways to do this. One (which I have used) is use the function `channel.connect()` to join a channel and return a VoiceClient object. Once you have a join client object you can use the function `VoiceClient.play()`. The parameters (found [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html)) accept an audio source. This is where FFMPEG comes in. Inside the parameters --> `VoiceClient.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("myAudioFile.mp3"))`.

If this line is having trouble finding the FFMPEG you can insert the path the executable like so --> `VoiceClient.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio( executable = "C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe" , source = "myAudioFile.mp3"))` Note the `executable` string and `source` string will vary for your FFMPEG location as well as your mp3 file location

All together this is what an example code would look like when used in the `on_voice_state_update` function:

`@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member,before,after):
    VC = await after.channel.connect()
    VC.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("MyAudioFile.mp3"))`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you install `PyNaCl` and import `nacl` and `os` for this.

**mp3 example:**

```py
@bot.command()
async def play(ctx):
    if ctx.author.voice.channel:
        if not ctx.guild.voice_client: # error would be thrown if bot already connected, this stops the error
            player = await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect()
        else:
            player = ctx.guild.voice_client
        player.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("your.mp3")) # or "path/to/your.mp3"
    else:
        await ctx.send("Please connect to a voice channel.")
```

---

**ytdl example:**

```py
@bot.command()
async def play(ctx, url=None):
    if ctx.author.voice.channel:
        if not ctx.guild.voice_client:
            player = await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect()
        else:
            player = ctx.guild.voice_client
        options = {
            "postprocessors":[{
                "key": "FFmpegExtractAudio", # download audio only
                "preferredcodec": "mp3", # other acceptable types "wav" etc.
                "preferredquality": "192" # 192kbps audio
            }],
            "format": "bestaudio/best",
            "outtmpl": "yt_song.mp3" # downloaded file name
        }
        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(options) as dl:
            dl.download([url])
        player.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("yt_song.mp3"))
        playing = player.is_playing()
        while playing: # not compulsory
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            playing = player.is_playing()
        os.remove("yt_song.mp3") # delete the file after use
    else:
        await ctx.send("Please connect to a voice channel.")
```

---

**References:**

- [`Member.voice`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.voice)
- [`VoiceState.channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceState.channel)
- [`discord.VoiceChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceChannel)
- [`VoiceChannel.connect()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceChannel.connect)
- [`discord.VoiceClient`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceClient)
- [`VoiceClient.play()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceClient.play)
- [`discord.FFmpegPCMAudio`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.FFmpegPCMAudio)
- [Download FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html)
- [Add FFmpeg to path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61821649/7808223)
- [youtube-dl docs](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/tree/master/docs)
- [`VoiceClient.is_playing()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceClient.is_playing)