# How to setup ffmpeg for discord.py on windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg, discord.py

I'm creating a discord.py bot that will play music and I'm having trouble using FFMPEG. The FFMPEG download is in my project folders but its still saying that it cant be found. The problem is probably that I havent added it to PATH but I dont know how to do that so if anyone could help me get it working that would be brilliant!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add FFMPEG to path, you're going to want to:

- Copy the path to `\bin` in the folder that FFMPEG was downloaded to.
- Open the start menu and search for "Edit environment varaibles".
- Click `Path` in the User Variables section:

  [image]

---

- Click `Edit...`:

  [image]

---

- Click `New`:

  [image]

---

- Paste in the path (might be slightly different, depends where you saved it - just make sure it ends with `\bin`):

[image]

---

- Now click `OK` in both menus to save your changes, and you should be good to go!